# Finding CSS changes in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I am doing a ajax form where I change some CSS elements on the fly, and I was wondering is it posible to check these changes within selenium, an example would be checking the background-color:#ffffff , click button,  background-color:#000000.

I have done a research on the net but can only find information on the 'css=' locator type which only give me locations of selector in the Dom model, not the css elements them selves.

is it possible to do what I have discribed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that I would do something like this is to do an assert on an attribute

```
css = selenium.getAttribute("locator@attribute");
```

and then do your asserts on that item that is returned. So if its a style you would do

```
css = selenium.getAttribute("locator@style");
```

or if its a new class do

```
css = selenium.getAttribute("locator@class");
```